# Windows Mobile 6.5 accessing files outside emulator

Tags: windows-mobile

I'm working on a Windows Mobile 6.5 application that uses a SQL compact database that I want to copy from the emulator back to the host. How can you access the emulator files directly from the host?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest mechanism is to configure the emulator to share a desktop folder.

1. Fire up the emulator of choice then go into File->Configure.
2. On the General tab at the bottom is a text box labelled "Shared folder"
3. Map that to a folder somewhere on the desktop.  On the device is will get mounted as 'Storage Card'
4. Put your database file in that location (as seen from the emulator).  It's now accessible from both the emulator and host PC.

Another option for just copying the file is to launch the Remote File Viewer, which is on your Start menu under Visual Studio 2008 -> Visual Studio 2008 Remote Tools.  That can connect to the emulator and pull down files manually.

Comment: Since the folder in question isn't changable in the client app, the first option won't work. Using the Remote File Viewer does work. Thanks.

Comment: 'Remote File Viewer' found on your Start menu -> Visual Studio 2008 -> Visual Studio 2008 Remote Tools. WORKS PERFECT :)